# Discrete Mathematics: Generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I know that stack exchange mathematics is not a site for asking question answer but for the sake of explaining the question I need to upload this question

[image]

> Is there any way that we can find the solution of this question by putting values in the answer and checking them? Or in other words can we find the solution from the options given rather than solving the generating function?

Comment: If $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...$ is a generating function for the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,...$, then $a_0=f(0)$, $a_1=f'(0)$, ... $a_r=f^{(r)}(0)/r!$. So yes, you could start from the given candidates and evaluate their derivatives at $z=0$ and check which satisfy the formulas above for the given $a_r$.

Comment: Of course. If you have a multiple choice question you can try each of the answers to see which work. If it's a well constructed question just one will. I this case, write out the power series representations of those geometric series and see which matches.

Comment: Do please take the time to enter critical parts of your question—in this case, pretty much the entire question—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. See [this part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) of [How To Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/265466).

Answer (score 0):

Try $z=\frac{1}{9}$. Then

$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_rz^r=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}3^{2+r}3^{-2r}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}3^{2-r}=9\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}3^{-r}=\frac{27}{2}$

and I think only one of the answer choices matches that value.

(Although writing down an expression for $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}3^{r+2}z^r=9\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(3z)^r$ is just as easy)